# How to search my database using php

Tags: php, html, sql, database, search

(Q) I have a web page that contains forms, and I want to be able to use the information that the user insert in these forms (after submitting) in order to run a SQL query and search the databese using php and show the results.

I successfully made a page that gets information from the user and insert these information to a table in the database, I think what I've explained in (Q) above should be similar to inserting but I'm stuck.

Heres the code that I wrote for inserting, it works, can You show me please how can I search the database?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    // Connecting to the database
$con = @mysql_connect('localhost','XXXXXXX','YYYYYYYY');
if (!$con) die("Could not connect to the server!");
if (!@mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXX')) die('Couldn\'t locate the database!');
// If form has been submitted - take action
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    // Inserting data to Branch
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Branch(branchName,address,size)
            VALUES('".$_POST["BRANCHNAME"]."','".$_POST["ADDRESS"]."',".$_POST["SIZE"].");";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // In case of failure
    if (!$result) {
        die("Couldn't add the part to the catalog.<br>".mysql_error());
    }


    // Inserting data to Customer
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Customer(memberNum,telephoneNum,firstName,lastName,birthDate,branchName)
            VALUES(".$_POST["MEMBERNUM"].",'".$_POST["TELEPHONENUM"]."','".$_POST["FIRSTNAME"]."','".$_POST["LASTNAME"]."','".$_POST["BIRTHDATE"]."','".$_POST["BRANCHNAME"]."');";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // In case of failure
    if (!$result) {
        die("Couldn't add the customer specified.<br>".mysql_error());
    }

    // In case of success
    echo "<b>The details have been added to the database.</b><br><br>";


}?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="9">
    <tr>
        <td>Member number</td>
        <td><input name="MEMBERNUM" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telephone number</td>
        <td><input name="TELEPHONENUM" type="text" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td><input name="FIRSTNAME" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name</td>
        <td><input name="LASTNAME" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Birth date</td>
        <td><input name="BIRTHDATE" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Branch name</td>
        <td><input name="BRANCHNAME" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><input name="ADDRESS" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td><input name="SIZE" type="text" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>

<?php
    // Closing the connection
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: For starters drop that error suppression `@`. Also you should really read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You need to switch to at least mysqli

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search for the customer and retrieve the data just do this:
    $search=$_POST['term'];

```
$sql="Select * from Branch,Customer where Customer.branchName=Branch.branchName and (firstName LIKE '%$search%' or lastName LIKE '%$search%') ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result&&mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
        $customername=$row['firstName'];
        $customerlastname=$row['lastName'];
    }
}
```

You can add as many fields as you want in the parenthesis ( or memberNum LIKE '%$search%')

To submit the search from the client just have an

```
    <input type="text" name="term">
```

in your form.

You do need to read the articles mentioned in the comments regarding sql injection but at your current level its better to get a feel of what going on and then proceed in learning about security.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to execute a query using the WHERE clause as a simple solution. [This article can get you started.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp) You can just use this to grab certain fields; [LIKE will also help you if you want partial matches.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools. Especially not on the topic of SQL, because that will only introduce security issues (namely SQL injection)

Comment: If you feel like my links are not of academic value, you're free to use SO's edit function to improve my links. I feel like the general concepts are still very much applicable. Thanks!